# Delete duplicates, but not after changing the values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables that has a lot of data about 8 Million and running in MySQL. So, what I need to do is to delete all the duplicates and retain only the first entry or value in the date column, but there's a different conditions after that. I will make a sample data below:

Columns are source, destination and date, I need to delete all the source and destination that has the same value and retain the earliest date entry, but for example the destination change and then after few minutes the destination values going back to the values that is same with what i need to delete, that values should not be deleted.

```
 Source Destination Datetime
    1        2         2017-01-01 23:45:46
    1        2         2017-01-01 23:46:46-this should be deleted
    1        3         2017-01-01 23:47:46
    1        2         2017-01-01 23:48:46-but not this one as the value for destination is changed from 3 to 2.
```

So, although the values of the destination at the last entry is the same with what on the first and second entry, that row or values should not be deleted as there's a changed happened on or from the third row or values.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Why is the `Datetime` column all empty, and you only have `Destination` in the first row?

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks for asking, I've edited the values and make much more clear what I want to delete and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user-defined variables to hold the `Source` and `Destination` from the previous row. When they're the same as the current row, output the `Datetime` in the result of the subquery. Then join this with the original table to get the rows to delete.

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT source, destination, IF(@prevSource = source AND @prevDest = destination, datetime, NULL) AS datetime, @prevSource := source, @prevDest := destination
      FROM yourTable
      ORDER BY datetime) AS t2
ON t1.source = t2.source AND t1.destination = t2.destination AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime
CROSS JOIN (select @prevSource := null, @prevDest := null) AS vars
```

If your table has a unique ID column, you could return that from the subquery instead of `source`, `destination`, and `datetime`, and join on that instead, which should be more efficient.

Comment: By the way, this makes my system down. :(

Comment: Is there any alternative ways on how can I achieve the goal here?

Comment: Make sure you have good indexes. As I suggested, if the table has an ID column, use that.